# Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm attempting to load a font in a practice project for `libgdx` like so.

```
package peace.at.steamd.screens;

import peace.at.steamd.Steamd;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;

public class mainmenu implements Screen{
Steamd game;
Stage stage;
BitmapFont black;
TextureAtlas atlas;
Skin skin;
SpriteBatch batch;
TextButton button;
public mainmenu(Steamd game){
    this.game= game;

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(delta);

    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.begin();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    if(stage== null)
        stage= new Stage(width,height,true);
    stage.clear();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    TextButtonStyle style= new TextButtonStyle();
    style.up= skin.getDrawable("buttonnormal"); 
    style.down= skin.getDrawable("buttonpressed");
    style.font=black;
    button=new TextButton("Press Me",style);
    button.setWidth(400);
    button.setHeight(300);
    button.setX(100);
    button.setY(100);
    stage.addActor(button);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch=new SpriteBatch();
    atlas=new TextureAtlas("data/button.pack");
    skin= new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
    black= new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/custom.fnt"),false);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    black.dispose();
    stage.dispose();

}
```

}

The custom.fnt is located in the proper directory and is linked etc. however when i run                the example i get this error.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: data/custom.fnt
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:823)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:99)
    at peace.at.steamd.screens.mainmenu.show(mainmenu.java:65)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at peace.at.steamd.screens.SplashScreen.tweencompleted(SplashScreen.java:82)
    at peace.at.steamd.screens.SplashScreen.access$0(SplashScreen.java:80)
    at peace.at.steamd.screens.SplashScreen$1.onEvent(SplashScreen.java:74)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.callCallback(BaseTween.java:380)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.updateStep(BaseTween.java:521)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.update(BaseTween.java:424)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.update(TweenManager.java:166)
    at peace.at.steamd.screens.SplashScreen.render(SplashScreen.java:42)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at peace.at.steamd.Steamd.render(Steamd.java:23)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:718)
    ... 15 more
```

when it reaches the point its attempting to load the font. I used the hiero web launcher to create the font and there is nothing special about the font file itself.
any ideas?

Comment: what version of libgdx?

Comment: Do you have the associated graphic file for the font in the right location? Open the custom.fnt with a text editor to check where it should go.

Comment: I'm working with 0.9.8. when I checked the font file its refers to "custom.png" which is located in the same directory as the .fnt file.
the android/assets/data/
do i need to change the reference to the filepath on my computer?

Comment: Hiero once gave me a corrupt font and many headaches, try regenerating it